# IOS: Retrieving custom object from userDefaults and NSCoding gives different value

Tags: ios, swift3, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I am trying to save custom object in UserDefaults, when I print the object, the retrieved object Id is different then saved object. Below is the code.

**Saving**

```
    let customAlertView:CustomAlertView = CustomAlertView()
       customAlertView.buyingRoleInnerStackView = contextInnerItem
       customAlertView.buyingRoleInnerArrStackView = contextArrInnerItem

       print("customAlertView :: \(customAlertView)")
```

//--> *Prints customAlertView ::CustomAlertView: **0x1702bc9e0**>*

```
let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: customAlertView)
   let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
   defaults.set(encodedData, forKey: AppConstants().KEY_CUSTOM_ALERT_VIEW)
```

**Retriving**

```
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

            if let viewData = defaults.object(forKey:  AppConstants().KEY_CUSTOM_ALERT_VIEW) as? Data {
               let alertView = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: viewData) as! CustomAlertView

                print("alertView :: \(alertView)")
             }
```

//--> *Prints alertView ::CustomAlertView: **0x1702be120**>*
        }

**CustomAlertView Class**

```
class CustomAlertView :NSObject, NSCoding {
     var buyingRoleInnerStackView:UIStackView!
     var buyingRoleInnerArrStackView:UIStackView!

override init() {}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        self.buyingRoleInnerStackView = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "buyingRoleInnerStackView") as! UIStackView
        self.buyingRoleInnerArrStackView = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "buyingRoleInnerArrStackView") as! UIStackView

    }
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

        aCoder.encode(self.buyingRoleInnerStackView, forKey: "buyingRoleInnerStackView")
        aCoder.encode(self.buyingRoleInnerArrStackView, forKey: "buyingRoleInnerArrStackView")

    }

 ....
}
```

Comment: That's the **memory address**. It **will** be different every time, and that has nothing to do with the contents (data) of the object.

Comment: I even printed accessibilityIdentifier of both views, while encoding I am getting correct accessibilityIdentifier, but after retrieving when i display I am getting nil.

Comment: I don't know the rules regarding the serialization of the `accessibilityIdentifier `. Perhaps you need to do it by hand in `init(coder:)` and `encode(with:)`.

Comment: Explicitly I am assigning the value of `accessibilityIdentifier` to the views. But while retrieving getting `nil`.

Comment: My guess is that perhaps you need to save the identifier manually in `encode(with:)` and restore it in `init(coder:)`...?